# reduce image file size in php by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am working on a script in which I have used a php code to display images from a specific folder on a webpage with the height and width of 1 pixel

```php
<?php 
  $files = glob("images/*.*");
  for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
  { 
   $num = $files[$i];
   print $num."<br />";
   echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" height="1px" width="1px" />'."<br /><br />"; 
  } 
?>
```

this script is working fine and display images on my webpage with the height and width of 1 pixel that are too small. but now I want to reduce images file size of each displayed image (that are showing with the height and width of 1 pixel ) on a webpage to avoid webpage loading issue. Anyone help me by jquery or javascript to reduce image file size.

Comment: You need to amend the file as it's stored on the server. By the time JS code gets access to the image it's already been downloaded, so changing it's size then would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You can create thumbnail by using [imagecopyresized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) with php

or lazy loading image after event fired